# API creation of Opportunity and Primary Campaign

Tags: lead-conversion

1) When Lead is converted to an Opportunity, we want to ensure all Campaigns from Lead flow to Opportunity as Campaign Influence records.

This happens when User manually does the Lead Conversion happens.

But when we do the same Lead Conversion to Opportunity via Convert API, the Primary Campaign Influence flag is not checked.
All Campaigns from Lead is going to Opportunities but Primary Campaign Source is not checked.

2) Similarly, when User clicks on New Opportunity button on a Contact, the Campaign Members of the Contact goes into Opportunity as Campaign Influence.

But when we perform the same operation from Contact to Opportunity , the Primary Campaign Influence is not checked.

Can anyone please suggest if these Technical Issues are valid:

*We cannot set the Primary Campaign Source via Apex.

*Campaign Influence is not available for any Apex and API.

There are lot of Idea Exchange posts related to this like 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtSTAAY

Comment: What is your question? The Campaign field on Opportunity can be set in Apex which provides the Primary Campaign Source (and CampaignInfluenceAdjustment, if enabled), you can also create OpportunityContactRoles in Apex which causes SFDC to created the CampaignInfluenceAdjustment records for the associated Contacts. You cannot create CampaignInfluenceAdjustment objects directly using the API.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty limited in these areas, but not totally out of luck.

You can set the primary campaign influence for an opportunity by setting the `CampaignId` field. So if you're creating an opportunity for a contact, you'd need to query their campaign history and chose the appropriate campaign and use that to set the field. The opportunity will then have the chosen campaign show up in the campaign influence.

Per @Alex_Tennant, it sounds like you can also use the `OpportunityContactRole` table to get some extra magic. Based on his comment creating those records will pull in the campaign influence for those contacts.

In general, I avoid doing any custom lead conversions so that I don't miss out on any auto-magic with Salesforce's conversion process. For new opportunities you can stick to using url-hacking which gives you access to URL params which can control whether contact roles or campaign influence comes over.

Answer (score 1):

CampaignId field and creating an OpportunityContactRole for the contact being converted will definitely recreate the standard conversion process via Apex.

You should check out this app on the appexchange: [Campaign Influence Analyzer& Contact Role Creator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5kDjEAJ)

It automatically analyzes all the relevant campaign responses within an account, effectively replacing the need to set Primary Campaign and Contact Roles via Apex in this scenario. It's cheap too.